# Run Mallard Basic .com program on Windows 8?

Tags: basic

Is there a way to run an app written in Mallard Basic on modern Windows?
I've tried to make a shortcut to the COM, which already caused some error messages, and then to run it in compatibility mode for an older Windows, to no avail. It says "This app can't run on your PC".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COM` applications are 16-bit and cannot be run at all on x64 systems (this is actually [CPU restriction, not Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Windows)):

> 16-bit Windows (Win16) and DOS applications will not run on x86-64
>   versions of Windows due to removal of the virtual DOS machine
>   subsystem (NTVDM) which relied upon the ability to use virtual 8086
>   mode. Virtual 8086 mode cannot be entered while running in long mode.

So, you have 2 alternatives:

- Run Mallrad Basic in [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)
- Run Mallrad Basic in virtual machine with [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/)

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are all correct, but I suspect you are trying to run a CPM program on a PC which has a completely different instruction set. You need a Mallard Basic compiler/interpreter for the 8086 instruction set which I may be able to help you with. I write all my own commercial programs in Mallard Basic and run them on everything (DOS, Windows 95 to Win-10, Linux, etc).